# помогите с анализатором синтаксического разбора?

Tags: синтаксический-анализ

Имеется такая граматика языка :

```
    # Операции
OPERATOR #1 -> +
OPERATOR #2 -> -
OPERATOR #3 -> *
# Сравнение
COMP #1 -> ==
COMP #2 -> !=
COMP #3 -> <
# Начальный символ
S -> PROG
# Тело программы
PROG #1 -> var = RVALUE \n PROG # Присваивание значение переменной
PROG #2 -> int var DECLARE \n PROG # Объявление переменной
PROG #3 -> while ( COND ) { PROG \n PROG # Начало while блока
PROG #4 -> eps # Пусто
# Для работы с переменными, константами
OPERAND #1 -> var # Или переменная

OPERAND #2 -> const # Или константа
# Работа с правой частью
RVALUE #1 -> EXPR # Может быть без унарного минуса
RVALUE #2 -> - EXPR # А может быть с ним
EXPR #1 -> OPERAND EXPR_2 # Переменная / константа и дальнейшие операции
EXPR #2 -> ( RVALUE ) EXPR_2 # Может быть выражение в скобках
EXPR_2 #2 -> OPERATOR EXPR # А может быть знак операции и продолжение выражения
EXPR_2 #1 -> eps # Может ничего не быть
# Объявление переменной
DECLARE #1 -> = RVALUE # Может быть сразу с присваиванием
DECLARE #2 -> eps # А может и без
# Условие в while
COND -> OPERAND COMP OPERAND
```

Таблица разбора
[image: Таблица разбора]

Схема разбора
[image: Схема разбора]

Возникают следующие вопросы:  Почему в таблице разбора только 28 строк, ведь состояний в схеме разбора больше? Как может быть направляющий символ eps? И что такое в вашем понимании eps? Откуда в таблице разбора взялся столбец S и что в нем написано?

Несколько раз прочитал материалы по анализаторам , но вот эти вещи что-то не дошли.
Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас нет столбца S. Присмотритесь Внимательно - это такое же значение, как и все остальное в этом столбце, который, кстати, без имени. S - это старт разбора. Если я правильно помню, то это называется не терминальные символы.

eps - это такой специальный символ, который пустой, нулевой длины. Просто так бывает удобно.

> Почему в таблице разбора только 28 строк, ведь состояний в схеме разбора больше?

Потому что некоторые строки в таблице содержат больше 1 состояния. Посмотрите на это

```
PROG #3 -> while ( COND ) { PROG \n PROG # Начало while блока
```

тут как минимум одно состояния на while, два на круглые скобки и так далее. Получается где то так.

```
PROG #3 -> while ( COND ) { PROG \n PROG # Начало while блока
4          50    51 52 53 54 55 ....
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, но не могли бы вы помочь ещё с парой вопросов :  какой направляющий символ в итоге будет в состоянии 13? И как можно доказать, что данная  грамматика LL(1)???

Comment: в данном случае для 13 состояния это получается просто перевод строки. Из за особенностей грамматики. Как доказать? почитать определение.